# How to join/subquery for table containing split column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have query on BigQuery (Standard SQL)

I've two tables: "accs" and "domain" as follows.

"accs" table has column 'domains' containing comma separated values. Now I wanted these values into separate rows against each account, which I got using the foll. query:

```
SELECT account, industry, split(domain, ",") as splitdomain
FROM `ds.test.accs`
```

Output is

However I could not get "account" for each domain and it is displayed blank.

Query-1: How to get account against each domain?
Query-2: Against each domain I want "sales" and "profit" from "domain" table

I tried following code but I'm getting Null value for Sales and Profit. I don't know how to use alias in join condition.

```
SELECT account, industry, split(domains, ",") as splitdomain,sales,profit
FROM `ds.test.accs`
left join (select egdomain,sales,profit from `ds.test.domain`)
on domains=egdomain;
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can actually help you

Comment: Your split() statement generates an array.  You will need to UNNEST(splitdomain) and then use the flattened splitdomains in your join.

Comment: @Nikesh Mehta Did rtenha solution worked for you? Could you provide and answer of  what was your solution for this?